# Struggling with running Storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

Hi I'm a beginner learning React & I'm trying out Storybook and I am having the following error when I try to run Storybook. **I tried to update by using npm update, I thought there was conflict with my dependencies **

```
ERROR in ./.storybook/generated-refs.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: You gave us a visitor for the node type StaticBlock but it's not a valid type
    at verify (C:\Users\msngw\OneDrive\Desktop\SBook\myapp\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\visitors.js:112:13)
    at explode (C:\Users\msngw\OneDrive\Desktop\SBook\myapp\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\visitors.js:34:3)
    at Object.merge (C:\Users\msngw\OneDrive\Desktop\SBook\myapp\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\visitors.js:147:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\msngw\OneDrive\Desktop\SBook\myapp\node_modules\@babel\helper-replace-supers\lib\index.js:60:44)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\msngw\OneDrive\Desktop\SBook\myapp\node_modules\@babel\helper-create-class-features-plugin\lib\fields.js:13:52)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/client/manager/index.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/register.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/register.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/register.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-controls/dist/register.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/register.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-viewport/dist/register.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-toolbars/dist/register.js ./.storybook/generated-refs.js main[9]
```

Comment: Can you please share your storybook version? Is it 6 ?

Comment: Also, if there's dependency conflict it should be best resolved after removing the lock file and re-installing the packages.

Comment: @FaizaanKhan yes its version 6

Comment: There's a bug in version 6 with package dependency. Try removing the package-lock.josn file and running npm install again. If it works great. If it doesn't use the last version prior to 6.

Comment: It will be fixed in 6.1, but it's not yet released.

Comment: @FaizaanKhan thanks for the heads up 6 is messed up have been trying. Let me try the previous version will update if it works

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been already raised in the [Storybook repo](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11907). As mentioned there, removing yarn.lock and node_modules, then re-installing using yarn, fixed all issues.